# How to split up above single cell Address value into multiple cell value through macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, macros

How to split up the below single cell value into multiple cell value through macro ?

So, this...

```
A1 = MISS FirstName LastName***95*SPECIAL ROAD**LONDON SW92**SW929AB
```

...should split as below,

```
B1 = MISS
C1 = FirstName 
D1 = LastName
E1 = 95 SPECIAL ROAD
F1 = LONDON SW92
G1 = SW929AB
```

Any one can help on this?

Comment: Is that real personal data you're sharing there? I would strongly encourage you to remove it if that's the case.

Comment: so your delimiters are spaces and asterisk strings longer than 1? But not consistently?

Comment: The data is some what unimportant, as long as the structure remains in tact. Since we can't tell if the data you used was real or not, I've edited it

Answer (score 2):

Based upon the demo you've given,  and the fact you wrote "How to split up above single cell value into multiple cell value through macro as below," this does exactly that

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim address() As String
address() = Split(Range("A1").Value, "**")

Dim col As Integer
col = 66

    For Each Item In address

        If (col = 66) Then

            For Each Name In Split(Item, " ")
                Range(Chr(col) & 1).Value = Trim(Name)
                col = col + 1
            Next Name

        Else

        Dim newValue As String
        newValue = Replace(Item, "*", " ")

            If (newValue <> "") Then
                Range(Chr(col) & 1).Value = Trim(newValue)
                col = col + 1
            End If

        End If

    Next Item

End Sub
```

Comment: This is *really* clever, despite using an unsized array. +1